# Can not write out the value of a specific position inside array with json data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I add items to my array with this code.

```
var allItems = [];
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i) {
        allItems.push({
            theTeam: data[i]["TeamName"],
            thePlayer: data[i]["TeamPlayer"],
        });
    });
}
```

And if i use this code

```
$.each(allItems, function (i, val) {                                      
    console.log(val.theTeam);                                    
});
```

Resultning in printing all data on position theTeam. Like First row in console AC Milan Second row in console Inter. But i want to print out a specific position in the array. I tried something like `console.log(val[0].theTeam);`

But it gives me error Cannot read property 'theTeam' of undefined.

I want in this case my result to be only AC Milan.

**Update inculded Json data**

```
[{
"TeamName": "AC Milan",
"TeamPlayer": "Mange" },{
"TeamName": "Inter",
"TeamPlayer": "Daniel"}]
```

Comment: How does your json look like ?? Also where are you getting val from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

val is a variable that is local to the $.each() method call.  You have a global array called allItems -- not val.  Do allItems[0].theTeam.

And if that answer is not inline with what you're asking, then please be more specific.  Your question is a little vague, so I've done my best to interpret what you're looking for.  Cheers.

Comment: Great, i had made it harder for myself then i had to i guess. I will go with this solution since its working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the index you want to access, then you don't need a `.each()` loop, just access your item directly by its index, like this:

```
console.log(allItems[0].theTeam);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I think i will go with the other answear anyway since in the future i will not know the exact index.